# How do I get a 32bit int from "eax" 8 times into "ymm0"?

Tags: assembly, simd, avx, avx2

I'd like to perform some SIMD/AVX Instructions and for that I need a 256bit register filled 8 times with the same number. The number resides in a general purpose 32bit register.
What is the most efficient way to load the value into the register?

Comment: The way compilers do it, with `vmovd` + `vpbroadcastd`.  Or with AVX512VL, with `vpbroadcastd ymm0, eax`

Comment: @Peter's suggestion would be most straight-forward. Before AVX512, moving `eax` to memory and `vpbroadcastd` from memory could be better regarding port-usage in some circumstances (this needs more context for an answer ...)

Comment: Thank you @PeterCordes. I implemented your suggestion (first move into xmm0, then broadcasted xmm0 onto ymm0) and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Yeah, of course it works.  The only question is whether it's the most efficient way.  In many cases yes, but chtz makes an interesting point about trading different port pressure for latency.  Worth considering depending on surrounding code, if you can't just broadcast a value directly from memory in the first place.  But anyway, glad it helped I guess, but still, next time look at compiler output for a function that does `return _mm256_set1_epi32(x)`.